# How to fetch change History from Google Sheet using Google API v4 for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have created a python script to sync my DB with google Sheet using Google API V4

Here is my snippet,
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('mycred.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("WORKBOOK NAME").worksheet('SHEET NAME')
print(sheet.get_all_records())
```

but from above code, am getting entire sheet record, 
this is an auto sync using cron so fetching all the record all the time is waste of time.

Gone through [doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) but i didn't find it.

is there a way to fetch Change history alone from Google Sheet API?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the difference of each history cannot be directly retrieved by Google APIs. So I think that it is required to compare the current data and previous data using a script. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: I am also thinking the same. but it is complicated and expensive

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly see your goal, can I ask you about the sample input and output you want? Because from your question, I cannot understand about the detail values of `change History`. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: As Tanaike said, it's not possible to get the revision history from the Sheets API, though the Drive APOI has a [revisions method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions) which allows you to download and publish file revisions, it may be possible to apply this for your use case to compare and obtain file changes?